# AVD ignoring layout-large/file

Tags: android, layout, android-virtual-device, android-resources, qualifiers

I chose my emulator as a Nexus 7 through Android Studio.
It's size is "large".

But when I run my app on the emulator then it still prefers using the default "layout" folders resource files.

I tried using the "layout-sw600dp" qualifier but still with no luck.

The resource file in both layout folders have the same name "news_articles.xml".

See my basic code below:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements HeadlinesFragment.OnHeadlineSelectedListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.news_articles);
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You should change in **AVD Manager** -  Your Emulator **Edit** - **Show Advanced Setting** - **Custom Skin Definition** to "No Skin" and rerun the emulator.

Comment: It still doesn't help for me.